# x content type options nosniff

Tags: html, vb.net, security, web-config, x-content-type-options

I was recently asked by our security team to add x content type options no sniff to a site I was also recently handed over to.  After adding it in, it seemed to cause issues with user log in as well as block purchases that have been made through the site.  To my knowledge this only explicitly sets the content type to what it is set as on page load and shouldn't affect submission or log-in.

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
   <customHeaders>
     <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
   </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

I am looking at the pages as I did see this could possibly affect scripting but not seeing anywhere where it declares a content type.  This is put into an old site that is written in VB.net

Comment: Was this badly worded or anything?  Not usual for a post to be completely void of any comments or answers.  If anyone can provide feedback to make this a more appealing question, please let me know.

Comment: Yes it is badly worded. How do you know adding this caused the issue? What have you done to investigate this yourself and how did that go? Have you removed it and did the issue go away? What is the exact error that shows in your login pages?

Comment: @BazzaDP, some of that is part of the bigger issue as I am limited myself with what I can do.  I will edit it and reword this to provide hopefully a better question.